# Creating a Set of Arrays in java

Tags: java, arrays, set

I want to do something like

```
Set <String[]> strSet = new HashSet <String[]> ();
```

Is there an easy way to make a Set of arrays in Java, or do I have to code my own implementation? Adding an object to a Set checks the Object using equals(), which does not work for arrays.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Arrays don't override `equals` and `hashCode`, and so the `HashSet` will compare them based on reference equality only. Consider using `List`s instead:

```
Set<List<String>> strSet = new HashSet<List<String>>();
```

From the [`List.equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) documentation:

> Returns `true` if and only if the specified object is also a list, both lists have the same size, and all corresponding pairs of elements in the two lists are *equal*.

Comment: Will the Set framework automatically call this List.equals to filter duplicate String Lists or do I need to do it manually?

Comment: @jDub9 It should work automatically. Thanks to polymorphism, the `Set` implementation only needs to know to call `equals`, which is declared for all objects. `List` overrides the contract of equals to to match the quoted description.

Answer (score 8):

Use a `Set<List<String>>`. You can use [`Arrays.asList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) and [`List.toArray`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29) for conversions, as necessary.

Comment: +1 For mentioning `Arrays.asList` (which is a simple `List` view of the backing array).

Answer (score 4):

If you really need  `Set<String[]>`, there is no easy and elegant way for that, AFAICT. The problem is that arrays do not not override `equals()` and `hashCode()`, on the one hand. On the other hand `HashSet` class do not provide a possibility to pass some "strategy" to it that would implement hash code and equality computation externally (something like `Comparator`). So you might consider creating `TreeSet` with a custom comparator. Unfortunately, I don't know of any implementation of array comparator, so most likely you will need to write your own.

If it's ok for you to have `Set<List<String>>`, you can consider advice in other answers.